# (React + Vite) build error on ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build my project on the server side. It's working perfect on local. But when trying to build from the server it's getting stock after sometimes. Sometimes it's giving an error

```
error Command failed with exit code 137. 
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

I'm using version

```
yarn: 1.22.19
npm: 9.8.1
node: 16.20.1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.